# How to set values to array using foreach

Tags: javascript, foreach, knockout.js

How can I add values to an array using a loop. I have been added values to the array by hard cording values, but I need to add huge data to an array.so its so difficult to by hard coding. this part of my JS code.

```
function BModel(checkInOrEdit) {
    "use strict";
    this.Number = ko.observable("");
    this.Years = ko.observableArray(['', '2019', '2018', '2017', '2016', '2015', '2014', '2013', '2012', '2011', '2010', '2009', '2008', '2007', '2006', '2005', '2004', '2003', '2002', '2001', '2000']);
}

BModel.prototype = {

    addTo: function (isSupervised) {
        "use strict";
        this.fname($.trim(this.fname()));
        this.lname($.trim(this.lname()));

    },

    AcDone: function (result, stat) {
        "use strict";
        var validationResults = JSON.parse(result.d);
        var msgTitle = '';
    }
}


$(document).ready(function () {

});
```

I need to add values to `Years` since this year up to 1900.how can I do this. Currently, I'm hard corded.

```
this.Years = ko.observableArray(['', '2019', '2018', '2017', '2016', '2015', '2014', '2013', '2012', '2011', '2010', '2009', '2008', '2007', '2006', '2005', '2004', '2003', '2002', '2001', '2000']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advice to create a helper that returns a range of numbers in a regular array first. Then, you can use the helper to initialize your observable array.

**Pushing to an observable array in a `foreach` can have the risk of redrawing the DOM many, many times!**

Here's an example of a `range` helper (can be refactored to be more succinct) and an observable array:

```js
function range(from, to) {
  const dir = to > from ? 1 : -1
  return Array.from(
    Array(Math.abs(to - from) + 1),
    (_, i) => from + dir * i
  )
};

const years = ko.observableArray(
  [""].concat(range(new Date().getFullYear(), 1900))
);

ko.applyBindings({ years });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: years">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
function BModel(checkInOrEdit) {
  "use strict";
  this.Number = ko.observable("");
  this.Years = ko.observableArray();
  let lyears = [];
  for (let i = 1900; i <= new Date().getFullYear(); i++) { 
    lyears.push(i);
  }
  this.Years(lyears); // see comments
}
```

This is not the most elegant way but this is how you would do it if you wanted to use a loop.

Comment: Where should I apply this sir

Comment: that depends. but I updated my answer for a suggestion that is easy to implement.

Comment: Suppose I need to add years to array scince current year, so I can directly set 2019. how to add years to array since current year to 1999?

Comment: I didn't understand what you're asking. You want 1999-2019? Then change `i = 1900 to i = 1999`? Or do you mean the current year as a variable?

Comment: To write to an observable, you'll have to call it using `this.Years(lyears)`. The currrent code has a hard-to-spot bug that will cause `Years` to **not** be observable.

Comment: @user3297291 thank you. Was not familiar with knockout.

Comment: yeah current year I need.your ways is correct, can i use var instead of let? cos my browser not working with let

Comment: @Adam yes you can use var instead of let.

Comment: and one more problem.before years. I need to add empty value as I hard corded
`(['', '2019', '2018'])`

Comment: just change to `let lyears = [""]`

Comment: @Adam I suggest you look into the other answer as it is better.